# multiple associations in scope rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

here is my situation. I need to fetch questions from women if current user is man

i have

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_one :profile (profile has an attribute "sex")
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

how can i retrieve questions for men using scope ?
i saw in documentation an example

```
Post.where(author: author)
Author.joins(:posts).where(posts: { author: author })
```

but have 2 associations: question.user and user.profile

tried variants like this

```
scope :for_men, joins(user: :profile).where(user: {profile_sex: "woman"})
```

nothing works

Help me please :)

Comment: Try this `Question.joins(user: :profile).where(profiles: { sex: 'woman' })` (notice that you always have to use the pluralized version of the model's name in the where clause). Actually you have to use the exact same name as the table's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tricky one:

```
Question.joins(user: :profile).where(profiles: { sex: 'woman' })
              #^^^^ Question belongs_to :user (not multiple userS)

Question.joins(user: :profile).where(profiles: { sex: 'woman' })
                                    #^^^^^^^^ We use the table's name in the where clause
```

---

The `.where()` method expects a hash formatted like this:

```
where( { exact_table_name: { exact_column_name: 'wanted_value' } } )
```

To map it into SQL like this:

```
WHERE 'exact_table_name'.'exact_column_name' = "wanted_value"
```

---

**What is happening in your case:**

```
where(user: {profile_sex: "woman"})
# generates this SQL:
WHERE user.profile_sex = "woman"; 
# This implies you have a table called `user` with a column named `profile_sex`
```

But we want something like this (I guess):

```
where(profiles: { sex: 'woman' })
# generates this SQL:
WHERE profiles.sex = "woman";
# This implies you have a table called `profiles` with a column named `sex`
```